# Qt 5.15 - QSortFilterProxyModel with QAbstractTableModel crashing on dataChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, qml

I have implemented a custom QAbstractTableModel and I have run it through the QAbstractItemModelTester and there are no more issues in my model. However, I am now trying to implement sorting through a QSortFilterProxyModel and I can't seem to get anything working at all.

```cpp
void RDMSensorModels::UpdateDevice(ArtNet::ArtRdmDevice* rdmDev, const RDM::RDMProcessor::RDMDeviceModel& model, int pid) {
    if (s_RequiredPIDs.contains(pid)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_RDMDevices.size(); i++) {
            if (m_RDMDevices[i] == rdmDev) {
                emit dataChanged(createIndex(i, 0), createIndex(i, columnCount() - 1));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function, which emits the models dataChanged signal and I dont think there is a problem here, but after this signal is emitted the program crashes inside QSortFilterProxyModels internal dataChanged handler

[As I can't embed pictures in my questions yet, here is a link to where the debugger breaks inside QSortFilterProxyModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9uS5.png)

The weirdest thing about this is, that no matter what I pass to the dataChanged signal, the proxy_columns inside QSortFilterProxyModel is always empty.

[Here you can see in the debugger, that the container is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvtaI.png)

If it's any help, here is my QSortFilterProxyModel implementation, its completely empty basically.

```cpp
class RDMSensorSortFilterProxyModel final : public QSortFilterProxyModel {
    enum SortValue {
        MANUFACTUER_MODEL,
        UNIVERSE_DMXADDRESS,
    };

public:
    RDMSensorSortFilterProxyModel(RDMSensorModels *sourceModel, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent) {
        setSourceModel(sourceModel);
    }

    int SortIndex();
    void SetSortIndex(int value);

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const override;
    bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const override;

 private:
    SortValue m_SortValue = MANUFACTUER_MODEL;
};
```

```cpp
int RDMSensorSortFilterProxyModel::SortIndex() { return m_SortValue; }

void RDMSensorSortFilterProxyModel::SetSortIndex(int value) {
    m_SortValue = static_cast<SortValue>(value);
    invalidate();
}

bool RDMSensorSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex& sourceParent) const { return true; }

bool RDMSensorSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex& left, const QModelIndex& right) const {
    auto leftDeviceManufacturer  = sourceModel()->data(left, RDMSensorModels::Roles::DeviceManufacturerRole).toString();
    auto rightDeviceManufacturer = sourceModel()->data(right, RDMSensorModels::Roles::DeviceManufacturerRole).toString();

    auto same = QString::compare(leftDeviceManufacturer, rightDeviceManufacturer, Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0;

    return same;
}
```

Here are my QAbstractTableModel reimplemented functions

```cpp
QVariant RDMSensorModels::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {
        if (section < 1)
            return QString("Device");
        else
            return QString("Sensor %1").arg(section);
    }

    int RDMSensorModels::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return m_RDMDevices.count();
    }

    int RDMSensorModels::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return m_ColumnCount;
    }

    QVariant RDMSensorModels::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return {};

        int deviceIndex = index.row();

        switch (role) {
            case SensorGraphReadingsRole: {
                auto& readings  = m_RDMDevices[deviceIndex]->Sensors()[index.column() - 1]->LastReadings();
                auto maxElement = f_SensorMaxReading(index.row(), index.column() - 1);
                auto minElement = f_SensorMinReading(index.row(), index.column() - 1);

                QVariantList values;
                for (int i = 0; i < readings.size(); i++) {
                    values.push_back(Utils::Math::map(readings[i], maxElement, minElement, 0, 1));
                }
                return values;
            }
            case SensorMinReadingRole: return f_SensorMinReading(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorMaxReadingRole: return f_SensorMaxReading(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);

            case DeviceUIDRole: return f_DeviceUIDString(deviceIndex);
            case DeviceUniverseRole: return f_DeviceUniverseString(deviceIndex);
            case DeviceLabelRole: return f_DeviceLabelString(deviceIndex);
            case DeviceManufacturerRole: return f_DeviceManufacturerString(deviceIndex);
            case DeviceModelRole: return f_DeviceModelString(deviceIndex);

            case SensorRangeMaxValueRole: return f_SensorRangeMaxValueString(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorRangeMinValueRole: return f_SensorRangeMinValueString(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorCurrentValueRole: return f_SensorCurrentValueString(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorNameRole: return f_SensorNameString(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorCurrentValueNormalizedRole: return f_SensorCurrentValueNormalized(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorMinNormalValueNormalizedRole: return f_SensorMinNormalValueNormalized(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);
            case SensorMaxNormalValueNormalizedRole: return f_SensorMaxNormalValueNormalized(deviceIndex, index.column() - 1);

            case SensorValidRole: {
                auto sensorCount = f_DeviceSensorCount(deviceIndex);
                return sensorCount && (index.column() <= sensorCount);
            }
            default: return {};
        }
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> RDMSensorModels::roleNames() const { return s_RoleNames; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related... your `lessThan` implementation does not adhere to a strict weak ordering policy.  If `QSortFilterProxyModel` uses C++ standard library containers that could result in undefined behaviour.  Does the crash occur if you use a plain `QSortFilterProxyModel` rather than your own derived class?

Comment: @G.M. I just switched out my implementation to QSortFilterProxyModel
`s_RDMSensors          = new RDMSensorModels();
s_RDMSensorProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
s_RDMSensorProxyModel->setSourceModel(s_RDMSensors);`
Initialized like so. Still crashes, same place, same problem

Comment: Does it only crash when it's connected to a proxy model, or does it also crash if you connect the model directly to a view? For debugging, I'd suggest creating the start and end indicies separately, one at a time, before you make the call to `emit dataChanged(...)`. Then you can check that the indices are indeed valid before you pass them to `dataChanged()`.

Comment: @Carlton Yes it only crashes on the proxy model, I had connected the model directly to the view all the time, only now we needed to create sorting and filtering, so i tried the QSortProxyModel, and it kept crashing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out, trying to replicate the issue on a smaller scale made my brain neurons fire enough, that i figured out the problem. My model column count can change and it does change, however, I had not written anything that notifies about column count changing beginRemoveColumns and endRemoveColumns and beginInsertColumns and endInsertColumns. I implemented those in my code like so

```
void RDMSensorModels::UpdateColumnCount() {
        int sensorCount = 1;
        for (auto device : m_RDMDevices) {
            int deviceSensorCount = device->Sensors().size();
            if (deviceSensorCount + 1 > sensorCount)
                sensorCount = deviceSensorCount + 1; // +1 for device column
        }

        if (m_ColumnCount != sensorCount) {
            if (m_ColumnCount < sensorCount) {
                beginInsertColumns(QModelIndex(), m_ColumnCount, sensorCount - 1);
                m_ColumnCount = sensorCount;
                endInsertColumns();
            } else {
                beginRemoveColumns(QModelIndex(), sensorCount, m_ColumnCount - 1);
                m_ColumnCount = sensorCount;
                endRemoveColumns();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the proxy model now works as expected. Hopefully this helps anyone else having issues with QSortFilterProxyModel.

It's interesting to note that the QAbstractItemModelTester did not catch this problem as I would have expected it to as my model changes column count depending on the largest sensor count for devices currently found.